# How to print byte array in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

My requirement is to print a byte array using a wifi printer in Xamarin Forms. I have placed an image and a QR code to a screen and took a screenshot of it programmatically so that I have converted it to byte[]. Now I have to print it. I know that there is no direct way to do this and should implement dependency service for this. I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656086/9526582) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242714/9526582) but didn't work. Can anyone please provide a working example for this?

Comment: Can you add some more information to the question? What did not work about the two methods that you tried. what is the code that you are currently working with? Are you trying to print to PDF or just the screen? how does dependency service fit into the picture.

Comment: Print to what - an actual printer?  What kind of printer?   What does the byte array represent?  Is it printable text, or an image, a PDF, etc?

Comment: I have to print a picture and QR code. I have placed these two in a screen and took a screen shot of the screen programmatically and so that I have a byte[] of it.

Comment: Yes I have to print it using a wifi printer.

Comment: @NithinThampi I would also like to know the solution for this...